# Outlook 2016 doesn't call SynchronizeInBackground

Tags: outlook, mapi, outlook-2016

In case when `CMsgStore::QueryInterface` method queries for the `IID_IMAPISync` it returns my own implementation (CSync) of the [`IMAPISync` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/imapisynciunknown). Later the CSync object got two method calls of `CSync::AddRef` and then two method calls of `CSync::Release`.

Can anybody help me to learn why the `CSync::SynchronizeInBackground` method isn't called?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As explained in the tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers.You have not included syntactically valid code. Please see how to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that demonstrates your problem. Please take the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour , visit the https://stackoverflow.com/help and especially read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: improved formatting